# How to use MKNetwork framework for http proxy server in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, mknetworkkit

I want to use a proxy server when opening a url connection with objective-c.But I don't want to use any frameworks other than MKNetworkKit(a third party framework) in my project.Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKNetworkKit has no special support for HTTP proxies, but, because it uses `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest`, you can add proxy support as described in this answer: [How to add a proxy to `NSURLRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847858/ios-any-body-knows-how-to-add-a-proxy-to-nsurlrequest).

In short:

1. Implement a custom `NSURLProtocol` that adds your proxy information to the request
2. Register your protocol with the URL loading system (`+[NSURLProtocol registerClass:]`)
3. Use MKNetworkKit as you normally would to load URLs with your custom protocol

Of course, it might be simpler just to use CFNetwork directly.