# how to add a prxoy server to my http requests via NSURLProtocol?

Tags: objective-c, proxy, nsurlprotocol

I need to proxy all my app's http and https requests trought a proxy server.

I cannot just change the url because most of the requets are done via 3rd party libs.

I tried some code from: [iOS any body knows how to add a proxy to NSURLRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847858/ios-any-body-knows-how-to-add-a-proxy-to-nsurlrequest) but it seems to not work or is incomplete.

Can someone give me a good example?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i ended up sorting this out with NSURLProtocol and ASIHTTPRequest.

I intercept in my NSURLProtocol class the request and send it to ASIHTTPRequest. Here i set up the proxy. Everything works fine!