# How to add a HTTPS proxy to NSURLSession in SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, swift, proxy, ios9, http-proxy

I have used the following code for connecting to the proxy server and works great for only HTTP requests but not for HTTPS. In iOS 9.0, **kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost** and **kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort** are depreciated.

```
let myPortInt = 12345;
let myProxyUrlString = "myProxyURL";

    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration();
    sessionConfiguration.connectionProxyDictionary = [
        kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable: true,
        kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort: myPortInt,
        kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy: myProxyUrlString,
    ]
    let url = NSURL(string: endPointUrl)
    let postRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)


    let jsonString =  bodyString
    postRequest.HTTPBody = jsonString 
    postRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    postRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)       
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(postRequest){}
```

Comment: I also want to do same.. Can u suggest any library/class to get Proxy done? I am trying hard to pass my webview traffic through the Proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for adding HTTPS proxy to NSURLsession

```
   let proxyDict : NSDictionary = ["HTTPEnable": Int(1), "HTTPProxy": myProxyUrlString, "HTTPPort": myPortInt, "HTTPSEnable": Int(1), "HTTPSProxy": myProxyUrlString, "HTTPSPort": myPortInt]

    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration();
```

Comment: This is not correct way as you never know when Apple will change their proxy strings then above code will fail